nodejs foreverkilled by SIGKILL
My nodejs server is killed by forever and throwing the following error.
{"level":"error","message":"Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGKILL"}

In my pakage.json file memory defined is 4076.
how can i resolve this issue and make sure that forever is not stopped?

You have to ask a question.
